# Как запустить exe и получить с него данные c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Собственно у меня уже есть код и он работает. Но на ASP.NET постоянно пустую строку выдает. Вот код:

```
public static async Task<string> RecognizeAudio(string path)
    {
        Process _process = new Process();

        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();

        startInfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\Макс\Downloads\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\Recognizer\dist\recognizer.exe";
        startInfo.Arguments = @"C:\Users\Макс\source\repos\ITG-Server\ITG-Server\Temp\382938128.wav";
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

        _process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        _process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        _process.Start();

        
        return await _process.StandardOutput.ReadToEndAsync(); ;
    }
```

И в консольном приложении все окей работает, но в ASP.NET я получаю пустую строку. Файл к которому я обращаюсь это питон код скомпилированный в exe. Как мне запустить этот код и получить инфу которую он возвращает.

```
public static async Task<string> Recognize(byte[] bytes)
        {
        //тут все работает
            string path = Audio.CreateFile(bytes, ".3gp");
            Audio.ToWav(path, ".3gp");
        //тут все работает

            return await Audio.RecognizeAudio(path);
        }
```

Contoller:

```
 [HttpPost]
 [Route("Verify")]
 public async Task<IActionResult> Verify([FromBody] Json json)
 {
     return Ok(await SoundModel.Recognize(json.content));
 }
```

Немного протестировать с другим ексе, все выводит. Видимо и правда что-то с прогой, хотя вроде все должно быть нормально. Буду пробовать дальше.

Comment: А эта программа вообще запускается?

Comment: Ага.  В консоли работает, а вот на сервере ASP.NET нет.

Comment: Не "Ага". Еще раз: этот exe-файл запускается, когда Вы делаете это из-под ASP.NET?

Comment: Скорее всего запускаемое приложение не работает и завершается, и ваш код здесь не при чем.

Comment: Как мне проверить запускается ли он из-под АСП? В принципе он ждет программу пока она сделает что надо примерно столько же сколько и консолька. В окно вывода никаких ексепшенов нету. Добавил больше кода

Comment: Хм, ну, например, файл создавайте.